# Store and access password using Apache airflow

Tags: python, airflow

We are using Airflow as a scheduler. I want to invoke a simple bash operator in a DAG. The bash script needs a password as an argument to do further processing.

How can I store a password securely in Airflow (`config/variables/connection`) and access it in dag definition file?

I am new to Airflow and Python so a code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 84):

You can store the password in a Hook - this will be encrypted so long as you have setup your fernet key.

Here is how you can create a connection via the UI:

[image: Main Menu]
Then:
[image: Create Connection]

To access this password:

```py
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook  # Deprecated in Airflow 2

connection = BaseHook.get_connection("username_connection")
password = connection.password # This is a getter that returns the unencrypted password.
```

**Update since Airflow 2 launch**

The library `airflow.hooks.base_hook` [has been deprecated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/_api/airflow/hooks/base_hook/index.html#module-airflow.hooks.base_hook) and you must use [`airflow.hooks.base`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/_api/airflow/hooks/base/index.html#module-airflow.hooks.base) instead.

Comment: Here's how to create the postgres connection string.  `connection_string = 'postgresql://' + str(connection.login) + ':' + str(connection.password) + '@' \
  + str(connection.host) + ':' + str(connection.port).encode('utf-8') + '/' + str(connection.schema)`

Comment: Can this be done from within an `Operator` (so that *downstream tasks* can reference the connection using `conn_id`)? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740885/create-and-use-connections-in-airflow-operator-at-runtime#comment94469298_53743774) for further elaboration of my query

Comment: I don't understand how merely *instantiating* a `Connection` object will create an entry in `Airflow`'s **meta-db**? Don't we have to perform a `session.add(..)` to persist it like [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L1166)?

Comment: This does not persist the connection at all, is there no way to do that outside of the UI? just initialising an object like @y2k-shubham stated, does nothing outside of the scope.

Comment: **@Havnar** you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863960/3679900) for dynamic `Connection` creation in Airflow

Comment: @y2k-shubham I've since figured a proper way to do things and posted my answer below.

Comment: In Airflow 2 `airflow.hooks.base_hook` gets deprecated and you must use `airflow.hooks.base`.

Comment: if he is trying just to store a password (like an API key) then a Variable is more adecuate than a Connection since they are also encrypted with Fernet (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html#securing-variables)

Answer (score 15):

This answer may be a little late, but I think it is important and still up to date:

When using

```
BaseHook.get_hook(conn_id=conn_id)
```

the credentials are logged as plain text into a log file by Airflow (we observed in version 2.2.3) under the path
`/var/log/airflow/scheduler/<date>/<dag>/`

You sure don't want you login and password there.

To avoid this, use `get_connection_from_secrets`like in:

```
from airflow.models import Connection
Connection.get_connection_from_secrets("<connection>")
```

This does not log any credentials into a file.

Answer (score 10):

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
conn = BaseHook.get_connection('bigquery_connection')
print(conn.get_extra())
```

These `conn.get_extra()` will give you JSON of the settings stored in the connection.

Comment: Just to clarify, `get_extra()` method returns a string, so you have to use `json.loads()` to grab it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

You can store the password in airflow variables, https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/ui.html#variable-view

1. Create a variable with key&value in UI, for example, mypass:XXX
2. Import Variable `from airflow.models import Variable`
3. MyPass = Variable.get("mypass")
4. Pass MyPass to your bash script:

```
command = """
          echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
          """



task = BashOperator(
        task_id='templated',
        bash_command=command,
        params={'my_param': MyPass},
        dag=dag)
```

Comment: The comment from @MatthijsBrouns is no longer true (for Airflow 1.9+).  Variables are stored in the DB encrypted.  However, be aware that their values are displayed in plain text in the Airflow web UI, if there's a chance you'll go browsing around there in front of someone who shouldn't see the value.

Answer (score 5):

Use the GUI in the admin/connections tab.

The answer that truly works, **with** persisting the connection in Airflow programatically, works as in the snippet below.

In the below example `myservice` represents some external credential cache.

When using the approach below, you can store your connections that you manage externally inside of airflow. Without having to poll the service from within every dag/task. Instead you can rely on airflow's connection mechanism and you don't have to lose out on the Operators that Airflow exposes either (should your organisation allow this).

The trick is using `airflow.utils.db.merge_conn` to handle the setting of your created connection object.

```
    from airflow.utils.db import provide_session, merge_conn




    creds = {"user": myservice.get_user(), "pwd": myservice.get_pwd() 

    c = Connection(conn_id=f'your_airflow_connection_id_here',
                   login=creds["user"],
                   host=None)
    c.set_password(creds["pwd"])
    merge_conn(c)
```

merge_conn is build-in and used by airflow itself to initialise empty connections. However it will not auto-update. for that you will have to use your own helper function.

```
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session

@provide_session
def store_conn(conn, session=None):
    from airflow.models import Connection
    if session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == conn.conn_id).first():
        logging.info("Connection object already exists, attempting to remove it...")
        session.delete(session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == conn.conn_id).first())

    session.add(conn)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would use a PythonOperator from which you are able to get a `Hook` on your database connection using
`hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=postgres_conn_id)`. You can then call `get_connection` on this hook which will give you a Connection object from which you can get the host, login and password for your database connection.

Finally, use for example `subprocess.call(your_script.sh, connection_string)` passing the connection details as a parameter.

This method is a bit convoluted but it does allow you to keep the encryption for database connections in Airflow. Also, you should be able to pull this strategy into a separate Operator class inheriting the base behaviour from PythonOperator but adding the logic for getting the hook and calling the bash script.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've used.

```
    def add_slack_token(ds, **kwargs):
        """"Add a slack token"""
        session = settings.Session()

        new_conn = Connection(conn_id='slack_token')
        new_conn.set_password(SLACK_LEGACY_TOKEN)

        if not (session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == 
         new_conn.conn_id).first()):
        session.add(new_conn)
        session.commit()
        else:
            msg = '\n\tA connection with `conn_id`={conn_id} already exists\n'
            msg = msg.format(conn_id=new_conn.conn_id)
            print(msg)

    dag = DAG(
        'add_connections',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="@once")


    t2 = PythonOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='add_slack_token',
        python_callable=add_slack_token,
        provide_context=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following utility method for creating a Session to an external db configuration saved in Airflow:

```py
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker


def get_session(conn_id):
    dbhook = BaseHook.get_hook(conn_id=conn_id)
    engine = create_engine(dbhook.get_uri())
    Session = sessionmaker()
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    return session
```